# Complex data query with pivot table in laravel eloquent or SQL

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, pivot

Please take a look at this example database schema

[image: Example Schema]

My users can have different grades of myopia.

So let's say I have a many to many relationship between users and contact lenses types.

A user can have many contact lenses in different colors and grades.

Now what I want to find is the number of different contact lenses grades (or colors) that users with the same myopia grades have.

That's to make some statistics.

For example I want to find out if people with same myopia grades uses the same contact lenses grades and what color they prefer more.

How would you get all those grades or colors given the premises (users with same grade of myopia) and with this DB schema? That's can be eloquent or SQL.

--- so far I tried this:

```
$user = Auth::id();

$myopia = $user->myopia_grades_id;

$example_lens_id = 1;

$users = User::with('contact_lenses_types')->whereHas('myopia_grades', function ($query) use ($myopia) {
    $query->where('id', '=', $myopia);
})->whereHas('contact_lenses_types', function ($query) use ($example_lens_id){
    $query->where('lens_id', '=', $example_lens_id);
})->get();


$lenses = [];

foreach($users as $i){

     $lens = $i->contact_lenses_types;

     $lenses[] = $lens;

};

return $lenses;
```

and it seems it's working in returning all lenses types 1 that users with same grade myopia as auth user has.

Comment: Care to show us what you've actually tried so far?

Comment: Actually I didn't try anything so far. I'm stuck thinking how can I get this data but can't think of anything good.

Comment: @iamgory I updated the question with what I tried so far. It seems it's working in fetching what I need. Now I have to understand how to manipulate the data.